# Adding a picture to a checkbox list after binding

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox

Is there any way to populate a checkbox list through datasource/ databind and then actually add an image to each checkbox? i know how to do both separately but cant seem to figure out how to make them work together.

Essentially i will have a checkbox list of students for teachers to select from and i've been asked to put a picture of each student next to the checkbox.

The way i get images currently is i have a webform which intakes an ID in the url and then it grabs the blob off the database then converts the binary into a thumbnail image, saves that locally then redirects to it. then when i want to get an image on a different webform i just need to use `Response.Redirect("imgs.aspx?ID=[Student Id]")` and it will put in a small image of the student, is there any way to modify a checkbox list so that i can call on the imgs webform and display the image of the student next to their checkbox?

Code behind imgs.aspx:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stuId = Request.QueryString["ID"];

        if (stuId.Length <= 0)
        {
            stuId = "100097645"; // If no ID number sent, display default 'image not available' thumbnail.
        }
        var con = new SqlConnection
        {
            ConnectionString =
                removed for security reasons
        };
        con.Open();
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select BINARY_OBJECT FROM BLOBS WHERE OWNER_REF=" + stuId, con);
        var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        reader.Read();

        var byteArray = (byte[])reader["BINARY_OBJECT"];
        var mstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        var dbImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray));
        var thumbnailImage = dbImage.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new IntPtr());
        thumbnailImage.Save(mstream, dbImage.RawFormat);
        var thumbnailByteArray = new byte[mstream.Length];
        mstream.Position = 0;
        mstream.Read(thumbnailByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(mstream.Length));
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BinaryWrite(thumbnailByteArray);
    }
```

code i have so far to display the image:

```
    private void StudentSelected()
{
    string query = "Select distinct (Convert(varchar, PERSON_CODE) + '|' + FORENAME + ' ' + SURNAME) as StudentName, (Convert(varchar, PERSON_CODE) + '|' +  FORENAME + '|' + SURNAME) as StudentValue From people where (FORENAME = '" + stuforename + "') and (SURNAME = '" + stusurname + "') and (Convert(varchar,PERSON_CODE) = '" + stuid + "')";
                StudentCheckBoxData.Merge(GetData(query));
                cbSelection.DataSource = StudentCheckBoxData;
                cbSelection.DataTextField = "StudentName";
                cbSelection.DataValueField = "StudentValue";
                cbSelection.DataBind();

            try
            {
                foreach (ListItem checkBox in cbSelection.Items)
                {
                    checkBox.Text += string.Format("<img src = \"{0}\" /> ", GetImageUrl(checkBox.Text.Split('|')[0]));

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                   //Display Error Here
            }

}
    private string GetImageUrl(string id)
        {
            return string.Format("http://bceforms/Contact/imgs.aspx?ID=", id);
        }
```

The problem at the moment is it shows the border but the image that appears is a Thumbnail not found image, when i've had this issue before it's been because image hasn't been databound however when i then use `.databind();` on the checkbox List because it obviously the original datasource doesn't have the image, it just removes the image

Any help would be apprecieated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is a good way in performance to save image data in sql, Instead you can save the image url in the sql and save the image file. And at the end of your code you have a problem:

```
private string GetImageUrl(string id)
    {
        return string.Format("http://bceforms/Contact/imgs.aspx?ID=", id);
    }
```

You must change that to this:

```
private string GetImageUrl(string id)
    {
        return string.Format("http://bceforms/Contact/imgs.aspx?ID={0}", id);
    }
```

After fixing this, Please let know the result.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!